# Collision Detection in Jetpack Compose

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-developer-api

I have a LazyVerticalGrid that will create a grid with 2 columns with the Boxes from a list.
Every Box is draggable. How can I trigger some action while onDrag() if the box I'm currently dragging is overlapping another box

e.g.: When I drag a box around the screen, every time I overlap with another box, the color of the border of the box overlapped to change to red.

[image: Overlap Example]

Like in this image (Item 2 is still onDrag, is not dropped), I will like to perform some action on item1, which is bellow item2 while is overlapped

Comment: You can take reference from this blog: https://blog.canopas.com/how-to-drag-and-drop-using-modifier-draganddropsource-target-jetpack-compose-bd4117f6c4bc